# Evaluating the Taylor polynomial of a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis

I have the following piecewise function.

$$f(x) =
  \begin{cases}
      \hfill \dfrac{\sin(x)}{x}    & \text{ if $x \neq 0$ } \\[6pt]
      \hfill 0 \hfill & \text{ if $x = 0$} \\
  \end{cases}$$

I want to find the first three non-zero terms of the Taylor polynomial at zero. However I'm confused about how to do this, as it seems that $f^{(n)}(0) = 0$ for any $n$th derivative of $f$. Therefore the Taylor polynomial is $0$. I would be grateful for a push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The second derivative is negative if $x=0$ (provided you say $f(0)=1$ rather than $f(0)=0$). It's not continuous at $0$ if $f(0)$ is anything besides $1$.
$$
\sin x = x - \frac{x^3} 6 + \frac{x^5}{120} - \cdots
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{\sin x} x = 1 - \frac{x^2} 6 + \frac {x^4}{120} - \cdots
$$